# Using equalizer in NAudio loopback

Tags: c#, naudio, equalizer

I wrote this simple method using **NAudio** to create a **reverb** effect on the current sound device. It's already working.

However, I would like to apply the reverb effect only on the higher frequencies, because otherwise you hear a lot of base drum echoes, which isn't what I want it to sound like.

```
private void CreateReverb()
{
    WasapiLoopbackCapture waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
    BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveIn.WaveFormat);
    VolumeSampleProvider volumeProvider = new VolumeSampleProvider(bufferedWaveProvider.ToSampleProvider());
    WasapiOut wasapiOut = new WasapiOut(AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 0);

    wasapiOut.Init(volumeProvider);
    wasapiOut.Play();
    waveIn.StartRecording();

    waveIn.DataAvailable += delegate(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        volumeProvider.Volume = .8f * ReverbIntensity;
    };
}
```

I tried some code I found online that creates an equalizer, but I couldn't apply it to my existing code.

**Question:** How do I change this reverb effect to only affect higher tones using some kind of euqalizer?

Comment: Generally speaking, you'd use the equaliser to set up a hi-pass filter on the sound source, preventing bass frequencies (say 200Hz or lower) getting through and then send that part of the audio stream to your reverb method.

Comment: I found and tried `BiQuadFilter`, but it doesn't provide a method that transforms a buffer (only a single float, not byte[]). I have yet to discover that class/method within this weird object model of NAudio. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with any of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon **`BiQuadFilter`** and it turns out that it can be used for that purpose.

It converts a sample as a float, while `WasapiLoopbackCapture.DataAvailable` returns a `byte[]`. But `BitConverter` can convert the float into the `byte[4]` and `Buffer.BlockCopy` writes it back to the stream.

**This is a working reverb including an equalizer.**

```
private void CreateReverb()
{
    WasapiLoopbackCapture waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
    BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveIn.WaveFormat);
    VolumeSampleProvider volumeProvider = new VolumeSampleProvider(bufferedWaveProvider.ToSampleProvider());
    WasapiOut wasapiOut = new WasapiOut(AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 0);
    BiQuadFilter filter = BiQuadFilter.HighPassFilter(44000, 200, 1);

    wasapiOut.Init(volumeProvider);
    wasapiOut.Play();
    waveIn.StartRecording();

    waveIn.DataAvailable += delegate(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.BytesRecorded; i += 4)
        {
            byte[] transformed = BitConverter.GetBytes(filter.Transform(BitConverter.ToSingle(e.Buffer, i)));
            Buffer.BlockCopy(transformed, 0, e.Buffer, i, 4);
        }
        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        volumeProvider.Volume = .8f * ReverbIntensity;
    };
}
```